# How to improve the performance of this function?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

This function takes around 1.2 seconds to execute. I am unable to understand why? Is it because of the inner joins? If yes, then how can i improve the execution speed? I am using Microsoft Enterprise Library.

```
  Public Shared Function GetDataByInterests(ByVal accountId As Integer) As Object


            Dim details As New List(Of GetIdBasedOnInterest)()
            Dim getIDs As New GetIdBasedOnInterest

            Dim interests As String = ""

            Dim db As SqlDatabase = Connection.Connection


            Using cmdGeneric As DbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT Interests.InterestName FROM UserInterests INNER JOIN Interests ON UserInterests.InterestID = Interests.InterestID WHERE UserInterests.AccountID=@AccountID")
                db.AddInParameter(cmdGeneric, "AccountID", SqlDbType.Int, accountId)
                Dim dsInterests As DataSet = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmdGeneric)
                For i = 0 To dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                    If i = dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        interests = interests & dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString
                    Else
                        interests = interests & dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString & ","
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
    getIDs.InterestName = interests
            details.Add(getIDs)

            Return details
        End Function
```

Comment: You must first trace and see the speed of your select command on your sql server.

Comment: Run the SQL for a typical accountID in SSMS. How long does it take (you can select the current date/timestamp before and after to see)? That will indicate whether the time is being spent in SQL or in your VB code. Is InterestID indexed on both tables (i.e. is defined as an index or is the primary key)? If not, that will slow the query if the tables are large.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing anything of the underlying tables and their indexes (and this is a check you should do immediately) there is an obvious problem in your loop.
You cancatenate strings, this, potentially could pose a strong pressure on the memory used by your program.
A string concatenation results in a new string allocated on the memory and thus, if your table contains many rows, the effect could be noticeable.

You could try to use a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2839d5h5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

```
Dim interests As new StringBuilder(1024) ' suppose an internal buffer of 1K'
...

If i = dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1 Then
    interests.Append(dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
Else
    interests.Append(dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString & ",")
End If

....

getIDs.InterestName = interests.ToString
```

Of course this optimization could be absolutely not important if your tables (`UserInterests` and `Interests`) are not correctly indexed on the fields `InterestID` and `AccountID`

**EDIT:** Another micro-optimization is to remove the internal IF test and truncate the resulting output only after the loop ends

```
For ....
    interests.Append(dsInterests.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(0).ToString & ",")
Next
if(interest.Length > 0) interest.Length -= 1;
```

**EDIT** As for your request, this is an example to create an unique index. The syntax could be more complex and varying depending on the Sql Server version, but basically you do this in Sql Management Studio

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX <indexname> ON <tablename>
(
   <columntobeindexed>
)
```

Check the [CREATE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms188783%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) statement examples on MSDN

Comment: `InterestID` and `AccountID` are auto increment Integers i.e `Identity` . So, do i still need to `Index` them. If so how? Does not Sql Server Index them automatically?

Comment: An `Index` and an `Identity` column are not the same thing. You should always place, at least, an unique index on an identity column if your system requires uniqueness. And an Identity column doesn't guarantee uniqueness (SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON/OFF)

Comment: How do i index an Identity column?

Answer (score 1):

1) Time your query in SQL Server Management studio.  It will be much easier to tune it there in isolation from your VB code.  Also you can run the display the query plan, and it ight even suggest new indexes.

2) Check you have the relevent primary keys and indexes defined.

3) Pull common expressions out of your for loop, to avoid recomputing the same thing over and over:

4) Like Steve says, use a StringBuilder

Combining those points:

```
            Dim theTable as ...
            Dim rowCount as Integer
            Dim interests As new StringBuilder(1024)
            Set theTable = dsInterests.Tables(0)
            rowCount = theTable.Rows.Count 
            For i = 0 To rowCount  - 1
                interests.Append(theTable.Rows(i).Item(0).ToString)
                If i <> rowCount - 1 Then
                    interests.Append(",")
                End If
            Next
```